# What does the second bracket in "var app = require('express')()" do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm quite new at the express framework.

I looked up at the Socket.io website for a quick start and I saw this statement at "Using with the Express 3 web framework". And in this line of the code snippet

```
var app = require('express')()
```

what does the second bracket use for?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thefourtheye answered your question, but here is a simplified example of what is happening.

Start by creating a file x.js with one function as shown below.

```
// x.js
exports.x = function() {
    return "hello";
}
```

And then requiring this file in another file.

```
// main.js
var x = require('./x.js'); // x is reference to the function
var text = x();            // execute the function (text will be "hello")
```

Alternative, you could have written

```
// main.js
var text = require('./x.js')(); // You are executing the function immediately
```

Answer (score 5):

When you say

```
require('express')
```

it is [this file](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L17), which gets executed and it exports `createApplication` function. You can check that, like this

```
console.log(require('express'));
// { [Function: createApplication]
//     mime: 
//      ...
console.log(typeof require('express'));
// function
```

It is basically a function with other data augmented to it (It is possible in JavaScript since functions are first class objects). Since, `require('express')` is actually a function, the second `()` means that we are invoking that function.

If you like to understand how `module.exports` and `exports` work, please check this [blog entry of mine](http://thefourtheye.in/2014/03/01/nodejs-modules-and-exports/)

Comment: So, basically referring to Hector Correa example. `require('express')` is just mention to include the whole class (module, or function) and second brackets is executing the `createApplication` in the express.js to be usable for the `app` object, Is this correct?

Comment: @sancowinx When you `require` a module, the code in the module will be executed and whatever is executed with `module.exports` will be returned. In this case, `require('express')` returns a function object. So, when we get a function object, we execute that with `()` notation. Thats it :)